# Set the value of a radio button to the value of an other input field in Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have several sets of radio buttons, the last one of which is an "other" field, in which the user can specify their "other" answer.

I would like to set the value of the "other" radio button to the value of the just-filled-out "other" text input field.

This is my html:

```
<fieldset>
    <h3>We are online via ...</h3>
    <label for="online_via[1]">
        <input type="radio" name="online_via" id="online_via[1]" value="laptop" /> Laptop
    </label>
    <label for="online_via[2]">
        <input type="radio" name="online_via" id="online_via[2]" value="desktop" /> Desktop
    </label>
    <label for="online_via[3]">
        <input type="radio" name="online_via" id="online_via[3]" value="mobile" /> GSM, Smartphone, PDA
    </label>
    <label for="online_via[4]">
        <input type="radio" name="online_via" id="online_via[4]" alue="tablet" /> Tablet
    </label>
    <label for="online_via[other]">
        <input type="radio" name="online_via" id="online_via[other]" value="other" /> Other, specify: <input type="text" id="online_via[specified]" class="other" />
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

As you can see, the last radio button contains within its label tag an input[type="text"]. I would like to take the value of that, and use it as the value of the other radio button. 
This is what I have been trying in Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.other').keyup(function(){
      var radio = $(this).attr('id').replace('specified','other');
      $('input#' + radio).attr("value", $(this).val());
      console.log($('input#' + radio).val());
    });
});
```

I keep getting "undefined". What am I doing wrong? Jquery jedis unite!

P.S.: Please keep in mind that I have several sets of radio buttons. 
P.P.S: The reason why the #online_via[specified] field does not have a name attribute, is because I would like to disregard it upon posting the data, since I wish to store its value inside the #online_via[other] field.

Looking forward to your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.other').keyup(function(){
      $(this).parent().find('input[type=radio]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Would that do it for you?

Comment: Wow! A true jquery jedi, you are! I'm accepting your answer, but SO tells me to wait 10 mins.

Comment: Just to clarify why your code didn't work, it's because of how jQuery use `[]` in selection. Its used as in the code above, to search for something on their attributes, so with your code jQuery was searching for a #id with an attribute of other. 

So you should just use alphanumeric in id's and classes.

Answer (score 0):

do this first:

```
<label for="online_via[other]">
        <input type="radio" class="otherClass" name="online_via" id="online_via[other]" value="other" /> Other, specify: <input type="text" id="online_via[specified]" class="other" />
    </label>
```

then:

```
$('.other').keyup(function(){

      $('.otherClass').val($(this).val());
      console.log($('.otherClass').val());
    });
```